# CSS Background Image Not Populating

Tags: html, css

Having trouble finding the relative path to my image in relation to my CSS folder.  Folder structure for image, CSS, and html is below (absolute path shown).

```
CSS - C:\Users\user\mpi\personal\static\personal\css\home.css
Image location - C:\Users\user\mpi\personal\static\personal\img\ex.jpg
HTML - CSS - C:\Users\user\mpi\personal\templates\personal\home.html

body {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       background-image:url(img/Ex.jpg);
       }
```

The above code will not produce my background image.  What's the correct relative path to get the background image to populate?  I can't even get the absolute file path to populate the image correctly.  I've looked at other question and answers with no luck.  Is the image location supposed to be relative to the CSS path, the HTML path, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have CSS in an external file all paths within that CSS use the relative path **of the external file**.

So when you have...

```
background-image:url(img/Ex.jpg);
```

It is effectively looking in...

```
background-image:url(css/img/Ex.jpg);
```

Instead, use the following...

```
background-image:url(../img/Ex.jpg);
```

Comment: The first option worked, the second did not.  Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @jvelt17 - glad I could help.  It's not an obvious one until it's pointed out.  I've removed the "second" option, which would have only worked if `img` and `css` were in the root of the website

Comment: @jvelt17 - if this was the solution to your problem, please don't forget to mark it as "accepted", so that other users know you no longer need any help with it (plus you get some useful reputation points at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write background image's path as if you are in the folder of the css file included, because it's like you are in C:\Users\user\mpi\personal\static\personal\css\ folder.
So in this case you have to write background:url(../img/ex.jpg);

Moreover i see that image name doesn't correspond; in your css class you have written Ex.jpg and in the complete image path you've written ex.jpg. Css detect uppercase and lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

**Image**
`background-image:url(img/Ex.jpg);`
Or

Starting with `../../` moves two directories

`background-image:url(../../Ex.jpg);`

**Css**
`background-image:url(css/Ex.jpg);`

Or

Starting with `../` moves one directory

`background-image:url(../Ex.jpg);`